# Speed up magento after set up

Tags: magento2, performance, varnish, php-7

so I've already set up a Magento site, it has been running for 1 month now. Now my question is is it still possible to get a performance boost now without losing any data. By that i mean can i upgrade from PHP5.6 -> PHP7 without losing anything or anything going wrong with the site, and can I install varnish with an already setup and running site ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento2 you should not have any problem upgrading to PHP7.
Upgrading to PHP7 will not cause any data loss since your information is stored in MySQL.

Upgrading to PHP7 will give you a great performance boost! Try it before using Varnish. Varnish is a good solution, but it is quite complex to configure to work correctly.

Instead of using Varnish try to use redis as cache and make sure you activated FPC Cache on your Magento.

Comment: Ok so upgrading PHP won't get me any problems on the magento 2 site reffering to 5.6 now? Using ubuntu, so just doing an sudo apt-get install php7.0 and a sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql for mysql should do the trick?

Comment: Yup, no problem on upgrade, just make sure to do it in the right way. You have to install php7.0 and all the required dependencies (like mysql, mcrypt and so on). I suggest you to make some test before doing it in production.

Comment: found it on the devdocs, this one should do the trick: sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv thanks !

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I just see that Magento has Varnish Caching as an option for Caching application within the FPC tab. Right now I'm on built-in application, which is not recommended for production use. Is it as simple as turning on Varnish Caching ? I see a configuration below it but it seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: You have to try it :) I'mnot a big fan on Varnish, but I have to say it is extremely fast when setup!